# How to access DMA in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, device-driver, dma

I am writing a device driver in Linux for which I need to implement `DMA`.

It is clear that `DMA` buffers can be allocated by a call to `pci_alloc_consistent()`. But how can we write commands to those buffers from user level?

Tasks include writing values to specific registers, how are these implemented using `DMA` commands?

Comment: When you say user level do you mean from user-space. Although there are approaches you can take generally user space has no visibility of DMA hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can write with DMA through I/O operations that you may access through a GNU C library . You must use system calls such as ioperm or iopl and run as root to gain access to DMA registers. At least thats how one gains access to IO space which may be used for DMA access. Though I may not answer the question completely, hopefully this points you in a good direction.